# serilog LoggerConfiguration via webconfig

Tags: serilog

How can I make LoggerConfiguration is manage via Web.config (appsetting) such as Verbose/Debug etc.

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .MinimumLevel.Verbose()// I want to make is configurable via web.config.
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()                    
    .WriteTo.Seq(serilogUrl)
    .CreateLogger();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`Serilog.Settings.AppSettings`](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-appsettings)

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .ReadFrom.AppSettings()
  ... // Other configuration here, then
  .CreateLogger();
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <appSettings>
    <add key="serilog:minimum-level" value="Verbose" />
    <!-- More settings here -->
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

Serilog's documentation is quite good. You should check it out:
[https://serilog.net](https://serilog.net/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the library that [@C. Augusto Proiete](https://stackoverflow.com/users/211672/c-augusto-proiete) linked ([Serilog.Settings.AppSettings](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-settings-appsettings)).

There is a good documentation with examples on [this](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/wiki/AppSettings) this page.